# Jquery - Prevent click event from being triggered through an overlying layer

Tags: javascript, jquery, z-index, layer

.PopBgd is 100% of the screens size with another div .PopUp contained within .PopBgd and appearing on top of it.
Clicking on .PopBgd gives the desired effect of Hiding. However clicking anywhere in PopUp also runs the fadeOut part of the script below.

**QUESTION**
How to prevent the fadeOut part of the script from triggering though overlying divs?

```
$('.BtnPop').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $($(this).data('popup')).fadeIn();
    $('.PopClose, .PopBgd').click(function() {
    $('.PopBgd').fadeOut();});
});
```

**ANSWER**

```
<button type="button" class="BtnPop" data-popup=".Pop1">CLICK</button>

<div class="Pop1 PopBgd">
  <div class="PopUp">
    <a class="PopClose">&#215;</a>
    <div>Content</div>
  </div>
</div>

$('.BtnPop').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $($(this).data('popup')).fadeIn();
});
$('.PopClose, .PopBgd').click(function() {
$('.PopBgd').fadeOut();});

$('.PopUp').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

**NEW QUESTION**
How to use StopPropogation when the target div's name is unknown?
What I have tried above does not work.

I resolved my additional problem by simply adding a second class name that was static to the desired div to allow stopPropogation to work as normal.

Comment: e.StopPropagation() may help

Comment: e.StopPropagation() does not work in my situation as I cannot declare the divs name as it is variable. What I tried above does not work for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('.Pop').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

[.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) "Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event."

Comment: Please add the HTML in your question, and if possible, a jsFiddle example.

Comment: I tried to create a jsFiddle for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/KrgzG/. One problem with your code is this `<div class=".Pop1 .PopBgd">` should be this `<div class="Pop1 PopBgd">`

Comment: You should see in my fiddle that clicking on the popup div with "content" doesn't cause the fadeout.

Comment: Thank you. Your suggestion helped me come to a resolution as posted above.